# Tabbing through rows in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid

I would like to be able to tab through rows in ag grid, rather than cells. I've tried setting the tabIndex of the rows in post, but it breaks once you sort/filter. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean it should select the first cell in each row (for example), or that it should select the entire row? What should it look like? What's the use case?

Comment: I want it to select the entire row, should look the same as when the row is hovered. The use case is so that the user can tab through and select/deselect rows, without tabbing through cells.

Comment: You could use the up/down arrow keys and space bar to select/deselect (this works with [the tables on this demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#gsc.tab=0), for example). Or you can implement a [`tabToNextCell` callback](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#gsc.tab=0) to get some of the way there with tabbing.